# Dequeue from a ConcurrentQueue only if a condition is met

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, locking, queue

How can I dequeue the next element of a `ConcurrentQueue` only if some condition is met?

E.g. if the next item to be dequeued fullfills a certain condition, dequeue it, otherwise leave it. Essentially a `'DequeueIf'` or `'TryDequeueIf'` method

Example:

```
var myQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<int>()
...
int item;
// only dequeue if the next item is 0
bool success = myQueue.TryDequeueIf(out item, x=>x==0)
```

It is of course possible to first call `TryPeek`, check the condition, and then `TryDequeue`, but that is no longer threadsafe.

I can wrap the whole `TryPeek & TryDequeue` in a lock, but that kinda defeats the purpose of using ConcurrentQueue; and means that all regular unconditional dequeues will also have to be locked. I am not sure whether I would even have to lock over every `Enqueue` to be save. If possible, I would like to avoid the possible pitfals of implementing my own lock-strategy.

Is there a lock-free solution using the .net4.0 `ConcurrentQueue` class or one of the other concurrent classes?

Answer (score 5):

This is not possible using built-in means. What to do?

1. Write your own simple queue. Just use a lock per queue. Unless you have a *very* high traffic on the queue this is going to perform just fine. Uncontended locks consume two interlocked operations per cycle.
2. Write a sophisticated queue using interlocked operations. Using a CAS retry loop you can implement a predicated atomic take operation. You probably can use the BCL source code as a starting point or as an inspiration.
3. Give up on the idea of having a queue. Doing this on a non-queue is easy. In case you draw the wrong item simply insert it back into the queue.

Answer (score 4):

As an add-on to @usr [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30337038/2573395):

> I can wrap the whole `TryPeek` & `TryDequeue` in a lock, but that kinda defeats the purpose of using `ConcurrentQueue`

Not really, or at least not fully, as one of its primary purposes is to coordinate producer / consumer rendezvous, and using a lock in this case will not block any producers, only other consumers. But this does mean you will need to use the same lock for all other mutating read operations.

So if that is not acceptable, you will either have to

1. Roll your own concurrent queue or a better data structure (heap?) implementation optimized for your specific usage pattern.
2. Consider an alternative approach that may fit your needs better: use a "push" or "event" based model instead of a "pull" based one. Using e.g. Rx and consumers that observe with a `where` filter.

Answer (score 1):

Most concurrentQueue implementations use a lock-free implementation to allow many producers and consumers to concurrently write the queue without blocking each other (except for the occasional spin-retry)

The base requirement for a conditional dequeue is an implementation of a 'pop if on top' function : 'bool dequeueIf(T)// Dequeues T if T is still the head, returns false if it is not the head; this allows you to :

```
T t=null;
do{ // need to spin in case the head changes between the peek and dequeue attempt
    done=-1; // assume failure
    T t2=peek(), 
    if (t!=null && someComplexCondition(t)) {// then it's what we want
        if(!dequeueIf(T)) // check to see if the head is changed
             {done=0;} // spin if the head is changed
        else {done=1;t=t2;} // it meets the criteria, and we de-queued it.
    }
} while (done==0);
// done = -1 == head does not meet criteria
// done = 1 == T contains poped item that met criteria
```

dequeueIf(T) needs to be implemented inside the queue.

In the case of a .Net ConcurrentQueue, then an modified version Dequeue(out T result) is needed : Dequeue(ref T toRemove).

This passes to a new version of concurrentQueue.Segment.TryRemove(out T result) : concurrentQueue.Segment.TryRemove(ref T toRemove)

This function needs to, before doing the compareExchange to de-queue, first compares the T at 'local' to the toRemove, and only removes it if it still top (otherwise it can assume that another threads TryRemove has already popped that value off the queue, so you can't return the value in question; toRemove should be nulled then).

Note; you can't overload f(out T) and f(ref T), so returning bool to indicate that you now 'own' the T you requested popped seems a reasonable solution, otherwise i'd use an overload of f( T toRemove) to allow the original function signature to be unaltered.